# Convertir PropertyName a KeySelector C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, automapper

Estoy implementando sorting en las peticiones de una API.

Primero instale este **NuGet**

> [AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping v3.0.5](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping)
>    Para convertir las expresiones de **DTOs** a **Entities**

Los `OrderBy` funcionaban correctamente con `ExpressionMapping` pero tener que crear un `ExpressionMapping` por cada propiedad en cada entidad es mucho trabajo y poco eficiente, es inclusive una mala práctica para cuando tenga que darle mantenimiento al sistema.

Por eso instale este otro **NuGet**.

> [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core v1.0.20](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/)
>    Para importar métodos `OrderBy` que soportan string. Ej: `users.OrderBy("name desc")`

#### Código

DTO

```
public class AuthorDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string MainCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Entity

```
public class Author : IAuthor
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string MainCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ICourse> Courses { get; set; }
        = new List<Course>() as ICollection<ICourse>;
}
```

Repository Query Author

```
public IEnumerable<Author> QueryAuthors(AuthorParameters authorParameters)
{       
    // query operations ...

    string orderBy = authorParameters.OrderBy; // OrderBy = "Name desc"
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orderBy))
    {
        // This works
        // gets converted to: authors => authors.OrderBy(a => a.FirstName);
        //Expression<Func<IQueryable<AuthorDto>, IQueryable<AuthorDto>>>
        //  dtoExpression = dtos => dtos.OrderBy(a => a.Name);

        // Thows System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException
        Expression<Func<IQueryable<AuthorDto>, IQueryable<AuthorDto>>>
            dtoExpression = dtos => dtos.OrderBy(orderby);

        var expression = _mapper.Map<Expression<Func<IQueryable<Author>,
            IQueryable<Author>>>>(dtoExpression);

        collection = expression.Compile()(collection);
    }

    // paging operations ...
}
```

Ahora cuando lo ejecuto me da el siguiente error.

```sh
   "An exception of type 'System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException'
   occurred in System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.dll but was not handled in user
   code: 'No property or field 'Name' exists in type 'Author''"
```

Estoy pensando hacer un extension method para `IQueryable<T>` con el objectivo de convertir los `propertyName` a `KeySelector` y aplicar `"asc/desc"` algo como:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplySorting<T>(this IQueryable<T> collection,
    string orderBy)
{
    var func = GetKeySelectorWithPropertyName<T>(orderBy);

    Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>>>
        dtoExpression = dtos => dtos.OrderBy(func);

    var expression = _mapper.Map<Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>,
        IQueryable<T>>>>(dtoExpression);

    return expression.Compile()(collection);
}

public static Func<T,TKey> GetKeySelectorWithPropertyName<T>(string orderBy)
{
    //TODO: get key selector from property name ...
}
```

EL problema es que no sé como implementar `GetKeySelectorWithPropertyName`. Si alguien conoce algún **NuGet** que haga esto por mí, o ha pasado por este mismo problema, me gustaría saber como puedo resolverlo, o si existe una mejor solución para el mismo.

Comment: El problema (mas alla de los nuget), cual seria? ordenar una lista de que forma?

Comment: El cliente solo tiene acceso a los DTOs por eso es agnóstico de las entidades. Lo que hace que los `OrderBy request` tengan que ser mapeados.

Comment: Perfecto.. te deje el comentario porque pedias una solucion mejor, pero no aclarabas el problema que querias solucionar ;)